# How to make a clear UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I got UIViewController with navigation controller, I push to other view controller. Is it possible to make this view controller with clear background?

This does not work:

```
if (!self.oneVC)
{
    self.oneVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"oneVC"];
}
self.oneVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.oneVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: What do you want to see below it? Pushing a view controller means there isn't anything else behind it. Do you want to present it over the top instead?

Comment: No, but in iOS 7 you can _present_ a view controller using a clear background, as I explain here: http://programming.oreilly.com/2014/01/transcending-uialertview-on-ios-7.html

Comment: Are you familiar with [UIPopoverController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)?  When you talk about trying to see one controller on top of another, that's the first thing that comes to my mind.  You might be looking for something along those lines.  It only works on iPad tho.